# Excel with SQL where clause: too few parameters?

Tags: sql, excel, where-clause, microsoft-query

Does anyone know why this statement fails?

```
SELECT * FROM `U:\file1.xlsx`.`table1` a INNER JOIN `U:\file2.xlsx`.`table2` b ON a.ID=b.ID WHERE a.receipt = credit
// Result: Too few parameters. Expected:1
```

It works without the WHERE clause, what am I doing wrong? I tried many versions (removing spaces, adding quotation marks etc.) but nothing helps.

Comment: I found the solution: single quotation marks were needed -_-' I had been trying with double all the time

Answer (score 1):

Enclosed credit in quotes.

Use below query.

```
SELECT * FROM `U:\file1.xlsx`.`table1` a
   INNER JOIN `U:\file2.xlsx`.`table2` b
   ON a.ID=b.ID
   WHERE a.receipt = 'credit'
```